# Mysql InnoDB error in Rails 3 when i run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, innodb, mysql2

`Mysql2::Error: Unknown table engine 'InnoDB': SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM schema_migrations`

This is the error I see when i run rake db:migrate. I am using mysql server `5.1` and rails `3.2.7`

Please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I already had a db and tables in the db. Some of these tables had similar names. I dropped the db and retried and it worked. So basically the error was very misleading.